# Date sortorder on GROUP BY with average

Tags: mysql, sql, select, sql-order-by, average

See the following query.

```
SELECT date_format(`date`, '%d %b %Y') AS Datum, 
       AVG(NULLIF(`temp` ,0)) AS Temp, 
       AVG(NULLIF(`cod` ,0)) AS CZV, 
       AVG(NULLIF(`nh4` ,0)) AS NH4 
FROM reactor1 
  GROUP BY `datum` DESC
```

This returns the correct data, but the sortorder for the date isn't correct. It sorts the date on a day basis.

```
01-NOV
05-NOV
07-DEC
09-DEC
13-NOV
```

What am I doing wrong here?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try this:

```
SELECT DATE_FORMAT(r.date, '%d %b %Y') AS Datum, 
       AVG(NULLIF(r.temp, 0)) AS Temp, 
       AVG(NULLIF(r.cod, 0)) AS CZV, 
       AVG(IFNULL(r.nh4, 0)) AS NH4 
FROM reactor1 r 
GROUP BY DATE(r.date) 
ORDER BY DATE(r.date) DESC;
```

Comment: Sorry, this sorts the date in correct order, but doesn't do the average. All data for a particular day are displayed.

Comment: @Mookie Check my updated answer and if it not works thn ptovide me the sample data so can find what is the problem at my end.

Comment: Sorry, didn't work either.
Easiest to me is to add a picture of the data. I used different columntitles in my question ;-)
![date reactor](http://www.vanmook.net/forumfoto/data_reactor.png)

Comment: @Mookie Check my updated answer. I am considering that you had stored only date without time in date column. But you are storing whole timestamp in date column. So I had used DATE function in Group by and Order by clause. Check now

Comment: You're the GREATEST. It worked.
had to change the IFNULL back to NULLIF to calculate the correct average. Sorry to put you on the wrong track by not mentioning I was using the timestamp

Answer (score 2):

Try this

```
SELECT date_format(`date`, '%d %b %Y') AS Datum, 
       AVG(NULLIF(`temp` ,0)) AS Temp, 
       AVG(NULLIF(`cod` ,0)) AS CZV, 
       AVG(NULLIF(`nh4` ,0)) AS NH4 
FROM reactor1 
  GROUP BY `Datum` ORDER BY `Datum` DESC
```

Comment: Using the alias (Datum) in GROUP BY or ORDER BY doesn't work. It still sorts the day.